# SQL Query Group Like Values within the same row and concatenate and sort others

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, unpivot, sql-server-2019

Using SQL Version 15.0.2000.5

I have a table with this data:

| StudentScheduleId | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | MondayStartTime | MondayEndTime | TuesdayStartTime | TuesdayEndTime | WednesdayStartTime | WednesdayEndTime | ThursdayStartTime | ThursdayEndTime | FridayStartTime | FridayEndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NULL | 9:00 | 11:00 | 11:00 | 12:30 | 9:00 | 11:00 | 11:00 | 12:30 | NULL | NULL |
| 31 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 0 | 2:00 | 3:15 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2:00 | 3:15 | NULL | NULL |

I want to achieve this format:

| StudentScheduleId | Schedule | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | T/Th | 11:00 | 12:30 |
| 15 | M/W | 9:00 | 11:00 |
| 31 | M | 9:00 | 11:00 |

I was able to do this using this query:

```
Select s.StudentScheduleId, 
    STRING_AGG(s.[Day], '/') AS Schedule, 
    s.StartTime, 
    s.EndTime
From
(
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'M' As [Day], s.MondayStartTime As StartTime, s.MondayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Monday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'T' As [Day], s.TuesDayStartTime As StartTime, s.TuesdayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Tuesday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'W' As [Day], s.WednesdayStartTime As StartTime, s.WednesdayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Wednesday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'Th' As [Day], s.ThursdayStartTime As StartTime, s.ThursdayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Thursday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'F' As [Day], s.FridayStartTime As StartTime, s.FridayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Friday = 1)
) As s
Group By s.StudentScheduleId, s.StartTime, s.EndTime
```

However, I have one concern and also one issue with the results.

1. Is there a better more proficient way of doing this considering performance or just being more succinct?  I don't expect this table getting to millions records, but I could see it growing into 100's of thousands eventually.
2. I tested other scenarios using more days of the week having the same start and end time and the schedule column result can come out in any order.  (Example: F/M/T/Th/W).  I would want this to come out in logical order M/T/W/Th/F.  I know about the WITHIN GROUP sorting for STRING_AGG but there's nothing to sort on or I'd need to add a sort column, any ideas?

Thank You for any help!

Comment: I gave my best try in a solution, but a comment on your SQL is, that since you know your queries return a distinct set of rows - use UNION ALLL, and not UNION. UNION is a set operator and it returns a distinct set. UNION ALL appends the results from each query, but does not do a distinct operation in the end, and demands way less resources in general.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly shorter solution for you:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (15, 1, 1, 1, 1, NULL, N'9:00', N'11:00', N'11:00', N'12:30', N'9:00', N'11:00', N'11:00', N'12:30', cast(NULL AS nvarchar(10)), cast(NULL AS nvarchar(10)))
    ,   (31, 1, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, N'2:00', N'3:15', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'2:00', N'3:15', NULL, NULL)
) t (StudentScheduleId,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,MondayStartTime,MondayEndTime,TuesdayStartTime,TuesdayEndTime,WednesdayStartTime,WednesdayEndTime,ThursdayStartTime,ThursdayEndTime,FridayStartTime,FridayEndTime)

SELECT  StudentScheduleId, starttime, endtime, STRING_AGG(shortcode, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY daynumber)
FROM    #data d
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES  (1,'M',monday, mondaystarttime, mondayendtime)
    ,   (2,'T',tuesday, tuesdaystarttime, tuesdayendtime)
    ,   (3,'W',Wednesday, WednesdayStartTime, WednesdayEndTime)
    ,   (4,'Th',Thursday, ThursdayStartTime, ThursdayEndTime)
    ,   (5,'F',Friday, FridayStartTime, FridayEndTime)
    ) v (daynumber, shortcode, day, starttime, endtime)
WHERE   v.day = 1
GROUP BY starttime, endtime,StudentScheduleId
ORDER BY StudentScheduleId, MIN(daynumber)
```

You can unpivot the days and times into rows which simplifies the aggregation a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to unpivot using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`, then group and aggregate it back up.

This will be more efficient than joins or unions, as it only uses a single scan of the base table.

```sql
SELECT
  s.StudentScheduleId,
  STRING_AGG(v.Day, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.Ordering) AS Schedule,
  v.StartTime,
  v.EndTime
FROM StudentSchedule s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
  ('M',  1, Monday,    MondayStartTime,    MondayEndTime   ),
  ('T',  2, Tuesday,   TuesdayStartTime,   TuesdayEndTime  ),
  ('W',  3, Wednesday, WednesdayStartTime, WednesdayEndTime),
  ('Th', 4, Thursday,  ThursdayStartTime,  ThursdayEndTime ),
  ('F',  5, Friday,    FridayStartTime,    FridayEndTime   )
) v(Day, Ordering, IsValid, StartTime, EndTime)
WHERE v.IsValid = 1
GROUP BY
  s.StudentScheduleId,
  v.StartTime,
  v.EndTime
ORDER BY
  s.StudentScheduleId,
  MIN(v.Ordering);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/wBRbETjv)

I hope I don't need to tell you that your data is denormalized: the data should have been stored in separate rows, not columns.

Comment: I'm having a deja-vu-feeling here

Comment: Sorry I only saw you posted after I posted mine.

Comment: Interesting tidbit, this database table was just updated FROM being stored in separate rows, which I already had working correctly.  Thanks for the answers, testing them out!

Comment: Tell whoever messed up your DB to go and put it right again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to sort the aggregated schedule using WITHIN GROUP and a case statement, which works for a known set of values.
You can find more information here: [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
Select s.StudentScheduleId, 
    STRING_AGG(s.[Day], '/') WITHIN GROUP (Order By CASE
                                                      WHEN [Day] = 'M' THEN 1
                                                      WHEN [Day] = 'T' THEN 2
                                                      WHEN [Day] = 'W' THEN 3
                                                      WHEN [Day] = 'Th' THEN 4
                                                      WHEN [Day] = 'F' THEN 5
                                                 END ASC) AS Schedule, 
    s.StartTime, 
    s.EndTime
From
(
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'M' As [Day], s.MondayStartTime As StartTime, s.MondayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Monday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'T' As [Day], s.TuesDayStartTime As StartTime, s.TuesdayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Tuesday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'W' As [Day], s.WednesdayStartTime As StartTime, s.WednesdayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Wednesday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'Th' As [Day], s.ThursdayStartTime As StartTime, s.ThursdayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Thursday = 1)
UNION
(Select s.StudentScheduleId, 'F' As [Day], s.FridayStartTime As StartTime, s.FridayEndTime As EndTime
From StudentSchedule s
Where s.Friday = 1)
) As s
Group By s.StudentScheduleId, s.StartTime, s.EndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a join on a dataset with weekdays and sort order. That way you only parse you source table once, in stead of once per weekday.

I join on the day which will pivot the table, and add one row per day
Then aggregate on schedule and start endtime, and aggregate day names ordered by sortcolumn:

The first CTE is simple your sample data, the CTE named cte, is the pivoted table, which is aggregated in the final step.

```
WITH tab
AS
(SELECT
        *
    FROM (VALUES
    (15, 1, 1, 1, 1, NULL, '9:00', '11:00', '11:00', '12:30', '9:00', '11:00', '11:00', '12:30', NULL, NULL)
    , (31, 1, NULL, NULL, 1, 0, '2:00', '3:15', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2:00', '3:15', NULL, NULL)
    ) a (StudentScheduleId, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, MondayStartTime, MondayEndTime, TuesdayStartTime, TuesdayEndTime, WednesdayStartTime, WednesdayEndTime, ThursdayStartTime, ThursdayEndTime, FridayStartTime, FridayEndTime))
,cte AS(
SELECT
    a.StudentScheduleId
    ,b.DayNm
    ,b.DayNum
   ,CASE
        WHEN DayNm = 'M' THEN a.MondayStartTime
        WHEN DayNm = 'T' THEN a.TuesdayStartTime
        WHEN DayNm = 'W' THEN a.WednesdayStartTime
        WHEN DayNm = 'Th' THEN a.ThursdayStartTime
        WHEN DayNm = 'F' THEN a.FridayStartTime
    END Starttime
   ,CASE
        WHEN b.DayNm = 'M' THEN a.MondayEndTime
        WHEN b.DayNm = 'T' THEN a.TuesdayEndTime
        WHEN b.DayNm = 'W' THEN a.WednesdayEndTime
        WHEN b.DayNm = 'Th' THEN a.ThursdayEndTime
        WHEN b.DayNm = 'F' THEN a.FridayEndTime
    END EndTime
FROM tab a
inner JOIN (VALUES ('M',1),('T',2),('W',3),('Th',4),('F',5))b(DayNm,DayNum)
ON
(   b.DayNm = 'M' AND a.Monday = 1)
OR( b.DayNm = 'T' AND a.Tuesday = 1 )
OR( b.DayNm = 'W' AND a.Wednesday = 1)
OR( b.DayNm = 'Th' AND a.Thursday = 1)
OR( b.DayNm = 'F' AND a.Friday = 1 )
)
SELECT StudentScheduleId
,STRING_AGG(DayNm,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY daynum)
      ,Starttime
      ,EndTime 
      FROM cte
GROUP BY StudentScheduleId
    ,Starttime
      ,EndTime
```